# Retrieve Picasa album from CDN image

Tags: picasa-web-albums

I often see Picasa images embedded in forum messages, but I sometimes would like to access to the albums they come from.

Flicker allows this kind of request using their API, [`flickr.photos.getInfo`](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.getInfo). You enter the CDN filename from the image link (`http://farmnumber.staticflickr.com/server/photo_id.jpg`) as the `photo_id`, and browse the information related.

Do you people know a way to achieve the same thing with Picasa?

Answer (score 1):

For **privacy reasons** it seems not to be possible finding out the username (or album id) just with the public photo_id. [See this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-picasa-data-api/Z96N8D0WgHc).